# Cloud Run service to service call getting 403 when VPC Accessor Enabled with "Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector" option

Tags: google-cloud-run

Do we have to route all outbound request through VPC accessor? What the "Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector" option for? Is it only for the service that don't call the another one?

Comment: What's your configuration? Did you set the ingress to internal only?

Comment: No, I have to access that services in my local environment. So,  the ingress configured as `Allow internal traffic and traffic from Cloud Load Balancing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the ingress to internal only or internal and cloud load balancing on your Cloud Run service, you can't access your service from outside (except if you use a load balancer).

So, in your case, you route only the private IP to the serverless VPC Connector. However, your Cloud Run service is always reachable on the internet, with a public IP. And thus, to access it from your VPC, you need to use the serverless VPC Connector for all traffic, private and public IPs.