# CloudRun Service to Service returning 403 After Setup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I have a service to service set up that I completed using the google cloud tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#nodejs)

1. Changed the cloudrun Service account to have `roles/run.invoker` (they both share the same role)
2. Make a request to get the access token: `http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https://XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-xx.a.run.app'`
3. (**failing**) Use that access token to make a request at `https://XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-xx.a.run.app/my-endpoint` with the access token: `axios.post('https://XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-xx.a.run.app/my-endpoint', {myData}, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUz.....'}})`

However, on step 3, making the call to my service, I receive a `403` error, any thoughts on what I missed?

Note: I have tried deploying my invoked service with `--allow-unauthenticated` and without it. I am not using a custom domain, I am using the CloudRun created url.

PS: If I change the ingress from `internal and load balancer` to `all` it works, however I'm not sure if this is correct to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP 403 Forbidden error message when accessing your Cloud Run service means that your client is not authorized to invoke this service.

You have not granted the service account permission to call the receiving service. Your question states that you added `roles/run.invoker` but the error message indicates you did not complete this step correctly.

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select the receiving service (this is the Cloud Run service you are calling).
3. Click Show Info Panel in the top right corner to show the Permissions tab.
4. In the Add members field, enter the identity of the calling service.
5. Select the Cloud Run Invoker role from the Select a role drop-down menu.
6. Click Add.

Note: When requesting the Identity Token, do not specify the custom domain. Your question's wording is confusing on that point.

[UPDATE]

The OP has enabled `internal and load balancer`. This requires setting up Serverless VPC Access.

[Connecting to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#egress%3Eegress%20settings)

Comment: I had my GCP consultant add it, and double checked it was added, so I believe it's definitely there. However, if I change ingress from `internal and load balancer` to `all` it works. Does that give any insight? Also, good point on the custom domain, I mistyped

Comment: I also added just now that both services share the same role

Comment: @KevinDanikowski - Very important detail that you left out of your question. Cloud Run is not part of your VPC.  For requests from other Cloud Run services or from Cloud Functions in the same project, connect the service or function to a VPC network and route all egress through the connector, as described in Connecting to a VPC network. Note that the IAM invoker permission is still enforced.

Comment: @KevinDanikowski see if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/68271019/7031308

Comment: I forgot to include the link https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#egress%3Eegress%20settings

Comment: @KevinDanikowski, the serverless VPC Connector is the key for you issue. Don't forget to route ALL the egress traffic to it. Cloud Run, even with ingress set to internal, is a public resource and public traffic access it.

Comment: @JohnHanley there are calls from `service-1` that *have* to reach the internet which the VPC connector - all - doesn't allow. Is there a way to let certain calls go through, or should I just make `service-2` ingress `all` and require authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add a VPC Connector and route all traffic through it. I added this to the deploy script `--vpc-egress all-traffic`. Originally I had `--vpc-egress private-ranges-only` to connect to redis `MemoryStore`, however this was insufficient to connect to my other service (*internal only ingress*).

Credit to excellent insight from @JohnHanley and @GuillaumeBlaquiere

**Interesting Note About NodeJS**: My container wouldn't start when I switched the `--vpc-egress` to `all-traffic`, and I had no idea why because there were no logs. It turns out running `node v16.2` caused some weird issues with `--vpc-egress all-traffic` that I couldn't debug, so downgrading to `14.7` allowed the container to start.

Comment: Hi @Kevin Danikowski. I have a similar use-case where my compute engine VM with private Ips would be calling my cloud-run service. I am getting 403. I have not set up the VPC connector as i believe it is for egress traffic. In my case the cloud-run is only going to accept the request from VM. It is not going to send back any response.

Comment: @Ambesh I'm not sure how to do that one, I've not had to use that scenario