# GCloud Cloud Run - service to service 403 with valid access token and correct invoker role

Tags: gcloud

I get a 403 calling a Cloud Run service from another Cloud Run service.

I can only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292944/cloudrun-service-to-service-returning-403-after-setup) relevant SO question but both the accepted answer checks and the OP's solution are not valid for my use-case.

Use case:

Service A (the called service):

- expose public routes to the internet (eg: `/public/...` )
- expose private routes (eg: `/internal/...`)
- expose a 403 custom route `/403` with JSON response

I have a subdomain configured using a Load Balancer with two rules:

- traffic to this subdomain pointing to `internal` is redirected to `/403`
- all the other traffic to this subdomain is redirected to my Cloud Run Service

My service is deployed with this config:

- Ingress Control is set to internal, with `Allow traffic from external HTTP(S) load balancer` flagged
- A VPC is configured, with `Route all traffic through VPC` set to true (the same VPC is used by all my services)
- Authentication setting is `Allow unauthenticated invocations`
- Service B's service account (the caller) is listed in Service A's permission tab under the Cloud Run Invoker role (same as PubSub's service account)

With this configuration:

- Traffic from the internet is served correctly through the subdomain
- PubSub can call Service A using the computeMetadata bearer token
- Service B gets a 403 using the https://xxx.a.run.app url

Service B obtains a valid computeMetadata token (the JWT is valid, claims are coherent), but 403 with this body is returned:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Access is forbidden.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

I am sure this is Google's 403 and not my custom 403 for it's not a JSON response and the request is not logged in Service A's logs.
I tried to allow all unauthenticated traffic and internal urls are served correctly, but I can not expose internal urls.

Does anyone have suggestion on what to check or how to debug this situation?